# Pandas: Create new column in DataFrame from other column requiring string manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame called df that contains the below data:

```
Index    Column1            Column2
0        SEP_2013_QUANTITY  4
1        SEP_2013_PRICE     4.99
2        JAN_2013_PRICE     8
3        JAN_2013_QUANITY   10.99
```

I need to create a DataFrame like the below.  The month is in format YYYY-MM-DD with day always being 15:

```
Index    MONTH       PRICE    QUANTITY
0        2013-09-15  4.99     4
1        2013-01-15  10.99    8
```

I have tried using string functions rsplit and replace in a new column creation statement, but I get an error that the string function is expecting a string and is receiving a Series.

I try something like:

```
df['new_column'] = str.rsplit(df.Column1,'_',1)[0]
```

This should return something like 'JAN_2013'.

I would also need to test the presence of _QUANTITY or _PRICE in Column1 to know whether to put the value in the new PRICE or QUANTITY column.

Thanks in advance for any help/guidance.

Comment: Try applying .str to your column and then use string methods of your choice: `df.Column1.str. ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you create a new column of 'Type' and then use `pivot`:

```
In [32]:

df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Column1.str.slice(4, 8) + 
                             '-'+ 
                             df.Column1.str.slice(0, 3) + 
                             '-15')
df['Type']  = df.Column1.str.slice(start=9)

In [33]:
#reset index if don't want date-time index
print df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Type', values='Column2')

Type        PRICE  QUANTITY
Month                      
2013-01-15   8.00     10.99
2013-09-15   4.99      4.00
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract just the month-year piece from the resulting list created by the split, apply `map` and a lambda to the result:

```
df['Column1'].str.rsplit('_', 1).map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Should give you just the MMM_YYYY pieces that is expected.

Or as @DSM suggests apply `str` again instead of the map-lambda:

```
df['Column1'].str.rsplit('_', 1).str[0]
```

Comment: Instead of the map/lambda, you could use `.str[0]` directly.